# Number of 15 minutes intervals between two datetimes

Tags: python, datetime

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()
start = now + timedelta(minutes = 15)
finish = start + timedelta(minutes = 30)
```

How can I find the number of 15 minutes intervals exist between start and finish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()
start = now + timedelta(minutes = 15)
finish = start + timedelta(minutes = 30)

elapsed = finish - start
number_of_intervals = elapsed / timedelta(minutes=15)
```

`elapsed` is the `timedelta` between `start` and `finish`. Divide by 15 minutes to calculate how many 15 minute intervals fit in there.

Note that this returns a float, so includes fractional intervals. Round as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the difference between start and finish in minutes, divide by 15, and make that an int:

```
now = datetime.now()
start = now + timedelta(minutes = 15)
finish = start + timedelta(minutes = 30)
difference = (finish - start).total_seconds()/60
quarters = int(difference/15)
```

Answer (score 1):

i would write something similar to this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

DATE_TIME_STRING_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'

from_date_time = datetime.strptime('2016-06-06T05:00:00.000Z',
                                   DATE_TIME_STRING_FORMAT)
to_date_time = datetime.strptime('2016-06-06T06:00:00.000Z',
                                 DATE_TIME_STRING_FORMAT)

date_times = [from_date_time.strftime(DATE_TIME_STRING_FORMAT)]
date_time = from_date_time
while date_time < to_date_time:
    date_time += timedelta(minutes=15)
    date_times.append(date_time.strftime(DATE_TIME_STRING_FORMAT))

print(date_times)
```

Output:

```
['2016-06-06T05:00:00.000000Z', '2016-06-06T05:15:00.000000Z', '2016-06-06T05:30:00.000000Z', '2016-06-06T05:45:00.000000Z', '2016-06-06T06:00:00.000000Z']
```

Edit:
If you are interested in just the number of 15 minute intervals you can use something like:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

```
DATE_TIME_STRING_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'

from_date_time = datetime.strptime('2016-06-06T05:00:00.000Z',
                                   DATE_TIME_STRING_FORMAT)
to_date_time = datetime.strptime('2016-06-06T06:00:00.000Z',
                                 DATE_TIME_STRING_FORMAT)

print((to_date_time-from_date_time) / timedelta(minutes=15))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `time` library instead of date time. `time` works with seconds and you should convert minutes to seconds:

```
import time
interval = 45*60
start = time.time()
finish = time.time() + interval
diff = finish - start
print(diff // (15*60))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply compare `start` and `finish` like so:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()
start = now + timedelta(minutes = 15)
finish = start + timedelta(minutes = 30)

elapsed = finish - start # This is a timedelta object

reference_interval = 15*60 # interval in seconds

number_of_intervals = elapsed.seconds/reference_interval
```

As pointed out by Sören, this will not work if 'elapsed' is more than one day, in which case, simply compute the number as follow:

```
number_of_intervals = (elapsed.days*86400+elapsed.seconds)/reference_interval
# (86400 seconds in a day)
```

Comment: Note that this will fail if `elapsed` is a day or more. Use `elapsed.total_seconds()` instead of `elapsed.seconds`